# How to remove all list items but one for one (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am looking for a way to remove all list items with one click, not that hard, but to give it some nice effect I wanted to let the first slideup and remove this, once the first is remove do the same for the second list item and so on, until every list item is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following removes all items in list sequentially at one time:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var $first = $('#list li:first')
    removeItem($first);
})


function removeItem($el) {
    $el.slideUp(function() {

        var $next = $el.next()
        if ($next.length) {
            removeItem($next)
        }
        $(this).remove()
    })
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/UzPy5/2/

To remove individually can use

Comment: nice but I have to click every button over and over. This also can be done with something like $('li').eq(0).slideUp().remove()

Comment: oops  I removed element too soon and didn't test it when I added line to `remove`..try updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/UzPy5/2/

Comment: if you want first item left in list start with `$('#list li').eq(1)` instead of `first()`

Answer (score 0):

Give all the list items the same class, then call $(".yourclass"), which will return an array. Then go through that array with something like setInterval (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) 
which can have your slideup function and your timing. Maybe for sliding you want (http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or some other plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Recursively `fadeOut` each element in the list. This could go without jQuery, but you'd need to roll-your-own animation (or use CSS animations).

```
function fadeList(list, index) {
  if (index < list.length) {
    list[index].fadeOut(800, function() {
      fadeList(list, i+1);
    });
  }
}

$('#remove-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  fadeList($('#my-list li'),0);
 });
```